# Realm ecommerce database design

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am playing with Realm for react native, and actually I am loving it.
I am trying to understand all its core concepts, in order to use all of its power.
I am trying to design the data structure for a simple ecommerce app, trying to take advantage of the "multi realm" feature.
The way I would like to design the data is the following:

- Create a public realm, where I am planning to put the products catalog and some other publicily available data
- Create a system realm, accessible only by the admin user where I have the list of all the users metadata (name, lastname etc)
- Create a realm for each user, where for example I am planning to store user's cart and user's orders

This would be, IMHO, a good design, because all user related data can be accessed only by the user and eventually the admin user, and all system data (eg: users) can be accessed only by admin users.

By the way, this kind of design suffers some drawbacks:

- Since there will obviously be a web backoffice, where for example there will be a list of all  orders, getting the list of all order of all users is going to be tricky because the orders are sliced into multiple realms.

The natural solution for such a problem, is to save the orders in a single realm, and use a where conditions to query data from any single user and adding a `userId` column in the orders table.

My doubt about this kind of solution, is that a potential malitious user, with a legitimate user token capable to read and write from that realm, could potentially read and write records belonging to other users. This happens because the realm's permission system allow you to grant permissions only at realm level, and at record level.

- The other problem is that in this design, the cart items are stored in the user realm. Obviously a cart item must contain a reference to the product, but the products are stored in the public realm. I can obviously query the products from the public realm, and then add a cart item containg a reference to a product, but the product saved in the public realm and the product saved in the user's realm are unrelated, meaning that if I change the product in the public realm, the changes are not reflected to the product object saved in the cart

Given your experience with realm, how would you address this problems?

Many thank